# Regex to return specific string match after x and before y

Tags: regex

Looking for regex to use in PowerGrep / VS Code for search replace. **SOLVED**

Sample Input with Desired Match (`shown as code`);

> any string here `type=Multi` any string here **end_type_a** *any string here before EOL*
> any string here type=Multi any string here end_type_b *any string here before EOL*
> any string here type=Multi any string here end_type_c *any string here before EOL*
> any string here `type=Multi` any string here **end_type_a** *any string here before EOL*
> any string here type=Multi any string here end_type_c *any string here before EOL*

I'm trying to replace the word **multi** with **single** if it is followed by **end_type_a** on the same line.

Some of the answers below (e.g. `/type=Multi(.*?end_type_a.*)/` produce multiple groups in the match which aren't handled by my text editors and do not give the desired result. https://regex101.com/r/AzPwWM/1

Cary's suggestion `(?:\A|^(?=.*\z))type=Multi` put me on the right track.

This worked for my use case: `(?:\A|(?=.*end_type_a))type=Multi` https://regex101.com/r/AzPwWM/2

Cheers for the help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us. After you make a good attempt at doing this yourself and if you still have problems, you can update your question with details of the specific problem and what you have tried, and include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we are able to help.

Comment: And please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Perhaps you want `(?:\A|^(?=.*\z))type=Multi`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/9MnNAI/2/). Move your cursor across the regex at the link to see details about the individual regex tokens.

Comment: Thanks Cary.. This put me on the right track.. ending up with `(?:\A|(?=.*end_type_a))type=Multi`

Answer (score 0):

If you try capturing the first group up to the positive lookahead assertion (?=...) you should be able to only replace the strings you need:

```
^type=Multi(any.+)(?=end_type_a)
```

This will capture UP TO "end_type_a" only when it exists in the string, capturing only the string prior to that substring not including "type=Multi" which you can then replace. Consider in python a multiline replacement would be performed as follows:

```
re.subn(r'^type=Multi(any.+)(?=end_type_a)', r'type=Single\1', str, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Cheers. I see how this works. I'm trying to use a text editor (VSCode) to do a search and replace but it selects the entire match up to "end_type_a". Any way around that?

Comment: I don't know VSCode but if it has PCRE compatible matches it should only match between the end of "Multi" and the start of "end". You could also try '^type=Multi(?=end_type_a)' and replace with 'type=Single' if that helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what lang you are in but this may help.

```
/type=Multi(.*?end_type_a.*)/
```

Then in js can do:

```
'type=Multiany string here end_type_a any string here before EOL'.replace(
  /type=Multi(.*?end_type_a.*)/g,
  'type=Single$1'
);
```

Results in:

```
"type=Singleany string here end_type_a any string here before EOL"
```

https://regex101.com/r/XDpEWL/2

Comment: Thank you. This seems to give me the same results as the other comment. It matches the entire string from "type..."  to "...type_a". I'm trying to replace the word "multi" with "single" if it is followed by "end_type_a" on the same line. Just using a text editor. Trying PowerGrep but so far the same result. Maybe i'll have to learn some JS / Python :) ?